# Correct use of sqlalchemy sesion with Flask

Tags: python, session, flask, sqlalchemy

I am trying to use sqlalchemy with flask(without the flask-sqlalchemy extension). I am struggling with how to integrate the session object of sqlalchemy with flask.

I have seen several approaches:

```
1) Create a new session everytime I want to query the database and close the corresponding session at the end of the request(in the request function itself rather than taking help from Flask). This does not scale well as it exhausts the sqlalchemy connection pool quickly with the number of increasing requests.


2) Use the scoped session, query the database and remove the scoped session acquired at the end of request using the flask's app.after_request decorator. This approach works, but I am confused so as how to make use of it, as some places recommend to use the Flask's global request variable g to keep track of which session is allocated to which request while others do not use it at all.
```

I have decided to use the second option, as the first option is not scalable at all for large applications.
I would like to know if there are any pitfalls with the second approach like concurrent sessions handling the same objects with or without the g operator. Also, does not using the g variable have any effect on sqlalchemy scoped_session?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: "without the flask-sqlalchemy extension"...could you clarify why you don't want to use flask-sqlalchemy given this is the natural path for using both flask and sqlalchemy. Hope you don't take this the wrong way, just looking for reason behind this decision

Comment: The codebase has become fairly large and I had earlier read some restrictions flask-sqlalchemy imposes, also using vanilla sqlalchemy does not impose restrictions on using a particular framework. This is a link to one of the posts I read https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/6izf95/what_are_the_advantages_of_using_flasksqlalchemy/ before continuing.

Comment: There’s no problem using `scoped_session`, just be sure to follow the declarative instructions carefully here: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/patterns/sqlalchemy/#declarative. No need to use `g` every call to the scopes session within the same request will return the same underlying session.

Comment: @SuperShoot thanks for the reply, could you cite some references where I could read more about how the scoped_session works, because I am just not able to wrap my mind around how the scoped_session is able to track which session to use for which request.